# Cannot name object created by psProjection in pst-solides3d

Tags: 3d, pst-solides3d

Consider the MWE below:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\psset{viewpoint=10 18 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=10,fontsize=10,unit=1}
    \begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-5,-4)(5,4)
    \psSolid[object=plan,definition=equation,args={[0 0 1 0]},fillcolor=red!10,base=-3 3 -3 3]

    \psSolid[object=point,args=0 0 0,name=A,linecolor=green]
    \psSolid[object=point,args=-2 2 0,name=B,linecolor=blue]
    \psSolid[object=vecteur,definition=vecteur3d,args=A B,name=v1]

    \psSolid[object=plan,definition=normalpoint,args={0 0 2 [0 0 1]},fillcolor=green!10,opacity=0.5,base=-3 3 -3 3,name=p2]

    \psProjection[object=point,definition=orthoprojplane3d,plan=p2,args=A p2,linecolor=green]
    \psProjection[object=point,definition=orthoprojplane3d,plan=p2,args=B p2,linecolor=blue]

    % THe next two lines wont work :(
    % \psProjection[object=point,definition=orthoprojplane3d,plan=p2,args=A p2,linecolor=green,name=foo]
    % \psProjection[object=point,definition=orthoprojplane3d,plan=p2,args=B p2,linecolor=blue,name=bar]

    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The points on the green plane are projection of the points in red plane, achieved by `definition=orthoprojplane3d`. If I try to assign a name to projection points however, there are errors and points are not created. According to page 174 of [this](https://www.sys.kth.se/docs/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pst-solides3d/pst-solides3d-doc.pdf) particular documentation at least, it should be possible to assign names. Giving name in my case is needed for later computations.

Comment: Yes, it is a bit odd. I did not find any example in the full manual in which a point gets named. These seem always to be more complicated objects.

Comment: With `tkz-euclide` there is a "pointer" to the results of previous computations -cannot call it from top of my head now- but something similar in `pst-solides3d` would solve my current problem here as well.